# “before delete post” action fire when the post is updated?

Tags: php, posts, notifications

I'm trying to create notifications only when I deleted published posts, but it fire when I update any published post?

What I'm doing wrong! Thanks.

```
function deleted_published_post_notify_author( $post ) {

    global $post;

    $send_published = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'published_send_once', true );
    if ( ! empty( $send_published ) ) return;

    if( current_user_can('administrator')) {

        if( get_post_status($post) == 'publish' ) {

        $post = get_post($post->ID);
        $author = $post->post_author;
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
        $link =  'https://www.cgartzone.com/submission-rules';
        $image = 'https://www.cgartzone.com/wp-content/themes/hitmag-child/assets/images/sad-icon-01.svg';
        $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('We are sorry to inform you that your artwork has been deleted. We recommended you to re-read our rules or contact us for more informations', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';
        $notif = array('title'=>$title, 'link' => $link, 'image' => $image);

        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'published_send_once', '1' );

        dwnotif_add_notification($author, $notif);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'deleted_published_post_notify_author' );
```

**Edit 1**

I tried to add `if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post ) ) return;` but nothing happen, How can i avoid this notification when I updating published post? It should fire only when I deleted the post! Any help please.

```
function deleted_published_post_notify_author( $post ) {

    global $post;

    $send_published = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'published_send_once', true );
    if ( ! empty( $send_published ) ) return;

    if( current_user_can('administrator')) {

        if( get_post_status($post) == 'publish' ) {

                    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post ) )
                       return;

        $post = get_post($post->ID);
        $author = $post->post_author;
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
        $link =  'https://www.cgartzone.com/submission-rules';
        $image = 'https://www.cgartzone.com/wp-content/themes/hitmag-child/assets/images/sad-icon-01.svg';
        $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('We are sorry to inform you that your artwork has been deleted. We recommended you to re-read our rules or contact us for more informations', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';
        $notif = array('title'=>$title, 'link' => $link, 'image' => $image);
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'published_send_once', '1' );
        dwnotif_add_notification($author, $notif);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'deleted_published_post_notify_author' );
```

**Edit 2**

I returned the empty trash to 0 into the wp-config.php like so `define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0);` that's because i don't need to keep them at all!

The original purpose that I need to delete any post permanently with the post attachments by using this action

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', function( $id ) {
  $attachments = get_attached_media( '', $id );
  foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, 'true' );
  }
} );
```

My blog for Artists and they uploading more images, So I deleting the post with the attachments to save some space in my host storage

Answer (score 2):

The hook `before_delete_post` fires before postmeta is deleted. That explains why it's not isolating the condition you want. Another part of the problem is you're trying to add postmeta while it is being deleted - it's not clear why you need `published_send_once` but you'll have to find another way to save that information than adding postmeta at the time all postmeta is deleted. Side note, posts of type "revision" cannot have the status "publish" - revisions always have a status of "inherit."

When a post is deleted, the hooks `transition_post_status`, `post_updated`, and `save_post` are all run. `transition_post_status` runs first of the three, so I'd suggest using it to trigger your notification:

```
// hook to transition_post_status
add_action('transition_post_status', 'wpse_test', 10, 3);
// the hook gives you the new status, old status, and post object
function wpse_test($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    // only run when the status changes from publish to trash
    // you might also want to only run when the post_type is attachment
    if($new_status == 'trash' && $old_status == 'publish') {
        // verify current user is an Administrator - by capability, not role
        if(current_user_can('update_core')) {
            // send notification
            $author = $post->post_author;
            $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
            $link =  'https://www.cgartzone.com/submission-rules';
            $image = 'https://www.cgartzone.com/wp-content/themes/hitmag-child/assets/images/sad-icon-01.svg';
            $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('We are sorry to inform you that your artwork has been deleted. We recommended you to re-read our rules or contact us for more informations', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';
            $notif = array('title'=>$title, 'link' => $link, 'image' => $image);
            dwnotif_add_notification($author, $notif);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this other hook will allow you to verify that your code only runs when a `publish` status post switches to `trash` status.

Comment: Thanks so much @WebElaine for your answer, but all my posts is deleted permanently not into the trash! So your suggestion will work with that?

Comment: I test it out but not working as i told you I'm deleting all posts permanently, So which hook work with that, Thank you!

Comment: How are you deleting the posts? As long as you're using a Core method (edit the post and hit trash, or bulk edit posts and hit trash, followed by emptying the trash) these hooks will run too.

Comment: You still have not explained how you are deleting the posts themselves. Are you using code? Or using steps in wp-admin? Or editing the database directly?

Comment: Yeah from wp-admin I hitting Delete permanently.

Comment: Then I'd suggest logging all of these hooks, performing your delete permanently action, and seeing which hooks run with which information to determine which one to use.

Comment: before_delete_post is working, but as my question title is fire when I updated the post!